# Examples of $L^p \cap L^1$ convergence

Tags: lp-spaces, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

I'm struggling to find examples of a sequence of functions in two different cases: let $1<p<2$

1. functions $(f)_n \in L^p(\Bbb{R},dx)\cap L^1(\Bbb{R},dx)$ such that $(f)_n$ converges strongly in $L^p(\Bbb{R},dx)$ but not in $L^1(\Bbb{R},dx)$
2. functions $(f)_n \in L^p(\Bbb{R},dx)\cap L^2(\Bbb{R},dx)$ such that $(f)_n$ converges strongly in $L^p(\Bbb{R},dx)$ but not in $L^2(\Bbb{R},dx)$

I've tried with a couple of functions involving characteristic functions on sets involving $n$, but can't seem to breakthrough. I appreciate any help!

Edit: for the first sequence I tried $f_n(x) =\frac{1}{n^{1/p}} \Bbb{1}_{[0,n]}(x)$, but the problem is that it's convergent in both $L^p$ and $L^1$ norms. I tried another similar sequence but the problem is always that I can't find a function that doesn't converge in neither norm

Comment: Can you add which functions you have tried?

Comment: Can you find a function in $L_p$ but not in $L_1$? Can you base your sequence on it? (Chop off tails.)

Comment: I added the functions that i tried. Not sure why finding and $L_p$ but not $L_1$ function would help since my sequence needs to be in both?

Comment: So, for 1), something like $\chi_{[1,n]}\cdot{1\over x}$.

Comment: Thank you! Got it now, also for the second part